# amount_paid is not updating for an order paid through Credit Card Direct Post (Authorize.net)

Tags: magento2, authorize.net

I am using `Authorize.net Direct post` as a payment method, for payment in my magento2 site. After successful order completion, `amount_authorized` attribute for that order is updated successfully but `amount_paid` was null. Do I need to add anything more in my configuration for fixing this issue?

Comment: Still have any doubt ?

Comment: Yes, My invoice generation is a third party service. I ma not using default magento2 invoice generation. So I need to populate the amount_paid for that service.

Comment: What ever service you use whenever invoice created in magento (via manual or third-party) this field will be populated.

Comment: As per your question answer is following please accept it and up-vote for Others and for good gesture in the community.  thansk

Answer (score 1):

`amount_paid` will be populated after order invoice generation.